# Javascript - Submit popup and without reload parent page in HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, popup

I have some issue on javascript popup
I need to open popup when I click one of the textfield in input form and then submit the popup, then get back to the main page (input form) to continue working on in without refreshing it.

I used the same implementation method and jquery like this --> [HTML 5 and CSS jQuery Log-in and Registration Popup Box - Adam Bray](http://www.adam-bray.com/blog/108/html-5-css-jquery-login-registration-popup-box/)

But then I failed to get back to the parent page withour refresh. It keeps reloading as I click the submit button.
I already read many questions related to this like --> [php ajax form submit without refresh parent page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17610388/php-ajax-form-submit-without-refresh-parent-page)
and this --> [javascript popup reloads parent page -](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595850/javascript-popup-reloads-parent-page) but still get nowhere near what I want with my code

And I already tried to use `preventDefault();` and `return false;`, hide the jquery, or changed type button form 'submit' into 'button' too.. but no luck, the popup even won't close instead.

this is the javascript I used

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#loginLink").click(function( event ){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".overlay").fadeToggle("fast");
});

$(".overlayLink").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var action = $(this).attr('data-action');
    
    $.get( "ajax/" + action, function( data ) {
        $( ".login-content" ).html( data );
    }); 
    
    $(".overlay").fadeToggle("fast");
});

$(".close").click(function(){
    $(".overlay").fadeToggle("fast");
});

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 27 && $(".overlay").css("display") != "none" ) { 
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".overlay").fadeToggle("fast");
    }
});
```

});

Close function for popup button -->

```
<script>
function closeSelf(){
window.close();
event.preventDefault();
}
```

and this is my button on popup -->

```
<button type="button" onclick="closeSelf(); return false;">DONE</button>
```

I've been struggling with it for days, Any advice will be appreciated ^_^

Oh and again I wonder, why won't native validation work on this popup ? It works on the parent though actually

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the ".overlayLink" click handler

```
$(".overlayLink").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
});
```

This handler, attached in this way, doesn't intercept form submission, and therefore cannot inhibit it.

To intercept form submission, you need to attach a handler to your form's 'onsumbmit' event, as follows :

```
$("#myForm").on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for fast response ^_^.  
I tried ur code. I changed my button back into submit, tried ur code and call it on `onclick' event in my button, but my popup won't close (O_o). And isn't $(".overlayLink").click(function(event) used to open th popup itself ?

Comment: Sylvie, in many respects, I know only as much as what is in your question. It would appear that the overlay has one or more links with `class="overlayLink"`, which when clicked is/are supposed to cause an ajax request to me made. So the code indicates NO, `$(".overlayLink").click(function(event)...` does not open the popup. (The popup is opened by clicking "#loginLink" and closed by clicking a ".close" link or pressing the keyboard's "escape" key.)

Comment: You need to install the code as I wrote it above, `$("#myForm").on('submit', function(event)`. Just make sure the "myForm" string matches your form's id. The normal order of events will be (i) user clicks "submit", (ii) form's 'submit' event is emitted, (iii) your submit handler fires, (iv) `event.preventDefault()` ensures the form is not submitted when the handler completes (and the page does not refresh), (v) ajax request is sent, (vi) server returns its response, (vii) your ajax success handler fires (viii) the returned data is displayed in the ".login-content" element of your DOM.

Comment: Oh yes.. It's #login link... :D I'm sorry...  the link I provided above is the exact same code method that I use, I was really thought that u already take a look. Sure... of course I make sure I'm using my own form's ID, and now nothing happened when the submit button is clicked, the popup not even close. Thanks by the way.. I'm still working on it, and when ur code work out, I will accept ur answer :)

Comment: Take a look in the console - see if the handler throws some sort of error.